# How to make multiple Fetch calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, fetch

I have multiple API calls with fairly lengthy, yet similar, response/error handling for each call.

**What is the best non-repetitive ways to make multiple independent api calls that update state using fetch?**

Copying and pasting 40+ instances of fetch doesn't seem right.

I want to avoid doing this ....

```
fetch(url,options)
   .then((response) => {
    // ...
    return response.json
    })
    .then((data) => {
    setState(data)
    //...
    })
   .catch((err) => {
    //Error logic here 
    })
```

***Here's what I've done so far:***

I made (*found and modified*) a useFetch hook...

**useFetch.ts**

```
//Only calls fetch() when .load() is called.
const useFetch = (path : string, HttpMethod : string, dependencies : any = [] , body : {} | undefined = undefined) => {

  const history = useHistory()
  
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<any>({});

  const [error, setError] = useState<string>("");

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const [controller, setController] = useState(2)

  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState<any>(false)

  const load = ():void => {
    setError("")
    //This prevents useEffect from triggering on declaration.
    if (isReady) {
      //Math.random() is just to get useEffect to trigger.
      setController(Math.random())
    }
  }

  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  let requestOptions:any = {
    method: HttpMethod,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "* always",
      Authorization: "Token " + token,
    }, 
  };
  if (body !== undefined) {
    requestOptions["body"] = {
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }
  }
  const URI = BASE_URI + path

  useEffect(() => {

    const fetchData = async () => {
      if (controller !== 2) {

        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
          const res = await fetch(URI, requestOptions);
          const json = await res.json();
          if (json?.action == "ENFORCE_BILLING" ) {
            history.push(BILLING_CREDENTIALS_PATH, { enforceBillingPopUp: true });
          }
          if (json?.action == "ENFORCE_SMS_CONFIRMATION") {
            // Should we log user out, as well?
            history.push(CONFIRMATION_CODE_PATH)
          } 
          if (res.ok) {
            setResponse(json);
            setIsLoading(false)
          } else {
            setError(json)
            setIsLoading(false)
          }
        } catch (err) {
          
          setError(err);
          // Error logic here...
          }
        }
      }
    };

  fetchData()

  setIsReady(true)

  }, [controller, ...dependencies]);


  return { response, setResponse ,error, isLoading, load, isReady };
};
```

**Component.tsx**

```
//Inside react functional component...

  // Prepares to fetch data from back-end
  const data1 = useFetch(PATH1, "GET");
  const data2 = useFetch(PATH2, "GET");
  const data3 = useFetch(PATH3, "GET");


  useEffect(() => {
    // Initial on load data fetch
    // .load() fetches data
    data1.load();
    data2.load();
    data3.load();
  }, [activeReservations.isReady]);
  // Sort data depending on sort selection


...
```

**Is useFetch considered bad practice? What are the advantages of using Redux, instead?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Redux is just state management; making states accessible across components. it doesn't particularly have anything to do with fetch requests.

Comment: @Roj Thank you for you reply. I've seen many people using Redux as a way to centralize api calls. I'm wondering how most people working on larger projects make api calls while maximizing code re-use (keeping it D.R.Y)

Comment: You may consider `useSWR` (https://swr.vercel.app/) library which will do most of your `useFetch` custom hook do now.

Comment: Yup. technically you could. It depends on the scale on your app and if different components can trigger the same requests while passing different params, in which case it might be better to keep it in your actions of state management, though this way is also fine.